# Set Default zoom in SSRS report viewer web part

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

Using SQL Server 2014, I have an SSRS report. I use the Reporting Services Viewer to display the report on a Sharepoint site, so users can view this report on the main page.

I need to set the default zoom to "Page Width". I know how to pass a zoom parameter within a URL, but I have no idea how to apply default zoom for an SSRS report viewer web part.

Hope for help with solution, if it is possible.

Comment: In the web part you need to enter the URL to the report, can't you use the zoom parameter there, like `rc:Zoom=Page+Width`? This only works for IE 5.0 and above btw.

Comment: SSRS report viewer web part uses the path to the file, not URL